# All my personal files are listed as untracked files

Tags: git, github, git-untracked

I don´t remember but I must have done `git init` in my personal file (`C:\Users\lucas`).

I want to upload a project to github. That project is in `C:\Users\lucas\Desktop\project` but for some reason VSCode tells me that every file in `C:\Users\lucas` are listed as untracked files.

I couldn't find the .git file in `C:\Users\lucas` but through PowerShell using `cd .git` I could access it. I tried to delete it but there are some files in there.

Should I delete this folder or does it contain important information? Is it supposed to exist a .git file in there?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you searched? This has been asked and answered soooooo many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initiated repository in your C:\Users\lucas.

Go to settings, set invisible files and folders to visible, delete .git folder

navigate to C:\Users\lucas\Desktop\project in terminal and run git init from there